# C# WinForm NotifyIcon Message shows behind taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote a Winforms application which uses `NotifyIcon`.

It works well, except on one computer, where the `NotifyIcon` message shows behind the taskbar (see the images, below). If I use another application at the same time, the application covers the message.

How can I make the NotifyIcon message show in front of the taskbar?

Here is my code:

```
 DeskMsg = new NotifyIcon();
 DeskMsg.Icon = SystemIcons.Application;
 DeskMsg.Visible = true;
 DeskMsg.Text = "Hello";
 DeskMsg.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "Hello", "Message", ToolTipIcon.Error);
```

**Behind**

[image: Wrong]

**Goal**

[image: Correct]

Comment: Which version of Windows is that?

Comment: It is windows XP professional SP3.

Comment: What about other systray applications? Do they show behind the taskbar too?

Comment: I suppose that this is rather a problem with Windows than with your application. Windows sometimes has strange problems bringing stuff to the front... Could be on that machine the task bar is set to auto-hide/topmost?

Comment: Thanks all. This problem is with Windows, I restart the explorer.exe, and it looks fine finally.